# Borders and gutters on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, gutter

I've started using bootstrap on a little project but I'm new at it.
I want to use some space between the boxes, i know that bootstrap stack the lines when using "margin" but padding has the same effect.

[image]

```
<!-- quickmenu - Start -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row quickmenu">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center quick-anim">
          <h4>Consultoria On-line</h4>
          <p>Conheça o potencial da sua loja virtual aos olhos de um especialista</p>
          <img src="img/consultoria-online.png" alt="Consultoria-online">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center quick-anim">
          <h4>E-commerce</h4>
            <p>Gerenciamento de inventário e ordens de compra</p>
          <img src="img/e-commerce.png" alt="E-commerce">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center quick-anim">
          <h4>Marketing Digital</h4>
            <p>Atraia mais visitas para poder vender mais</p>
          <img src="img/marketing.png" alt="Marketing Digital">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center quick-anim">
          <h4>Panejamento estratégico</h4>
            <p>Seguindo o caminho correto para obter os melhores resultados</p>
          <img src="img/planejamento-estrategico.png" alt="Planejamento-estrategico">
        </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- quickmenu - End -->
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
body {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: A little explanation or reference to documentation would be helpful.

Comment: @showdev it tells the browsers what size properties (width/height) would include.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I've solved this problem!
The solution was to use another div only to make a box padding.